# Set Auto-Reload in Jetty Programmatically

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I would like to set the scan interval in Jetty programmatically.

I have this right now:

```
        Server server = new Server(Integer.valueOf(System.getenv("PORT")));
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        server.setHandler(context);
        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new Run()),"/*");
        server.start();
        server.join();
```

How can I set the scan interval before I start the server?